# Android checkbox dialog (easy)

Tags: android, checkbox, dialog, if-statement, boolean

I have a dialog with checkboxes, and I was trying to do different things when options are selected and when <kbd>OK</kbd> is pressed.

I thought I knew what I was doing after reading some tutorials, but when I press <kbd>OK</kbd> it just toasts "Everything" even if it isn't checked. So it seems that my `if` statements are not working correctly, but I don't know why.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

```
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
    final boolean[] states = {false, false, false};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("What would you like to do?");

    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, states, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item, boolean state) {
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            SparseBooleanArray CheCked = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
            if(CheCked.get(CheCked.keyAt(0)) == true){
                Toast.makeText(Backup.this, "Item 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(CheCked.get(CheCked.keyAt(1)) == true){
                Toast.makeText(Backup.this, "Item 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(CheCked.get(CheCked.keyAt(2)) == true){
                Toast.makeText(Backup.this, "Item 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.create().show();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you use `keyAt`, which, according to the API documentation

> returns the key from the indexth
>   key-value mapping that this
>   SparseBooleanArray stores.

and this `SparseBooleanArray` contains only the checked items of your list (`getCheckedItemPositions`)!

So if you check two items of three, then the `CheCked` member will contain two items, and when you call `keyAt(2)` it will return 0 (not `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, though at that position the map does not hold a value).

You should simply use the `get` method of this `SparseBooleanArray`, with the item positions from your `ListView` as arguments:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
    {
        SparseBooleanArray CheCked = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
        if (CheCked.get(0))
        {
            Toast.makeText(TmpActivity2.this, "Item 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (CheCked.get(1))
        {
            Toast.makeText(TmpActivity2.this, "Item 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (CheCked.get(2))
        {
            Toast.makeText(TmpActivity2.this, "Item 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

You can also lose the `== true` part of the `if` clause, but that's just semantics.

If you take a look at the **API documentation** of the `getCheckedItemPositions` method, you find this solution:

**Returns**: 
A `SparseBooleanArray` which will return true for each call to **`get(int position)`** where `position` is a position in the list, or `null` if the choice mode is set to `CHOICE_MODE_NONE`.

Comment: @rekaszenu I think this solution is better too. Especially for large lists. Loop needs more resource.

Comment: It's (almost) always better using the api than workarounds, but in most of the cases it's just boring reading the docs; :) this results in handling the `CheCked` member as a full `Map` of the `ListView`'s items and their checked state.

Answer (score 11):

I would do it like this for example:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    CharSequence[] items = {"Google", "Apple", "Microsoft"};
    boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[items.length];

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case 0:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("Dialog with simple text")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    if (itemsChecked[i]) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[i] + " checked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which] + (isChecked ? "checked!" : "unchecked!"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .create();
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't want the things to run onClick though i want whatever is checked to run when okay is pressed and only when okay is pressed i can't have the items run onClick

Comment: edited my code, but I want you to think little harder. It's not so difficult to add for loop to onClick method and check which array item has a value of true :)

Comment: Sorry i'm pretty new to this been learning java in my spare time for the past month only but anyway been tired as hell as well lol been going at this app for the past few hours break time :) but your method worked great just like the other one i only gave the check to them because it was simpler since i already had that as my code and explained what i had done wrong wish i could give you guys both the checks but i gave you a vote up as well

Comment: how to unselect all that i pick ?

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
.setMultiChoiceItems(
    items, itemsChecked,
    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(
                getBaseContext(),
                items[which]
                        + (isChecked ? " checked!"
                                : " unchecked!"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
)
```

But then how do you use the checked items in another class?